# how to access a control's value that is placed in a panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DropDownList` control in a panel and this panel is in turn placed in a `SplitContainer`'s `panel1`. I changed the modifiers property to 'Public' for the `DropDownList` but I can't access this control from another class.

```
//created instance of the form
Payment pForm = new Payment();
```

I am able to access other controls which are placed outside of the split container as below.

```
string amount = pForm.tbAmount.Text;
```

But I can't access the dropdownlist control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A split container has 2 panels, and each panel has a collection of controls, so:

```
ComboBox dropdown = pForm
    .SplitContainer1       // get the splitcontainer control of pForm
    .Panel1                // get the first panel of this container
    .Controls              // get the controls collection
    .OfType<ComboBox>()    // find all controls that are of type ComboBox
    .FirstOrDefault();     // get the first or null if none
```

Obviously in order to be able to access `pForm.SplitContainer1` from outside of the `Payment` form class you will have to provide a public getter to it.

And if you wanted to further constrain by the name of the dropdown (assuming you had multiple dropdowns in this panel):\

```
ComboBox dropdown = pForm.
    .SplitContainer1
    .Panel1
    .Controls
    .OfType<ComboBox>()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "comboBox1");
```